# Avoid symbols conflicts dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, clang, cocoa-touch

I saw many online solution for the symbols conflict problem [symbols collusion problem in static libraries](http://pdx.esri.com/blog/2013/12/13/namespacing-dependencies/)

Basically the problem happens when framework consumer project (say A.project) import a framework (say B.framework) while B.framework import a third party framework (c.framework) which is also used independently in the A.project.
In that case a symbol collusion will happen at runtime:

> Class is implemented in both and . One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I am looking for a few weeks on how to resolve this for **cocoa touch framework that is a dynamic framework**. all the solutions i see is talking about static frameworks.

Many of the solutions say that the best way to go is **not** link the third party c.framework directly to the B.framework but tell the client to link it to the project.

But in this case my framework code wont build - if i remove the c.framework from the "link binary with Libraries" in the framework i develop B.framework the code cant compile saying module and objects are missing.

How can i make this happen? somehow use the third party framework C.framework classes without exporting them or reference instead of link

I really need technical help on this one

Comment: Can we have the actual errors being printed with the actual names of the frameworks ?

Comment: Yes the third party is GoogleMobileAds.framework the errors are "objc[7114]: Class GADGestureUtil is implemented in both VeediFramework and ...VeediDemoApp.app/VeediDemoApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined" this return for all the GoogleMobileAds objects

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problems recent days, and maybe we should use pod to import c.framework in case A.project imported B.framework with c.framework.

From apple's doc:

Note: Name conflicts between dynamic shared libraries are not discovered at compile time, link time, or runtime. The dlsym function uses string matching to find symbols. If two libraries use the same name for a function, the dynamic loader returns the first one that matches the symbol name given to dlsym.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryUsageGuidelines.html